# unable to sign the image using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cosign-api

I am trying to sign the docker image using cosign in jenkins pipeline. I got this error

```
"cosign version
/home/jenkins/workspace/eVisl-import-dev-cicd@tmp/durable-63e86c1b/script.sh: line 1: cosign: command not found"
```

Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('sign the container image') {
            steps {
                sh 'cosign version'
                sh 'cosign sign --key $COSIGN_PRIVATE_KEY hub.docker.com/hamzanasir6886/evsil-dev:latest-3'
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your PATH variable to add cosign executable.

```
environment {
   PATH = "/cosign_location/bin:${env.PATH}"
}
```

or something like the below.

```
  withEnv(["PATH+COSIGN=/cosign_location/bin"]) {
    sh 'cosign version'
    sh 'cosign sign --key $COSIGN_PRIVATE_KEY hub.docker.com/hamzanasir6886/evsil-dev:latest-3'
  }
```